# Why won't my Acer 5740g display on an external monitor?

Tags: windows-7, external-display

I'm having a frustrating time attempting to get my Acer 5740g to display on my external TV/monitor via HDMI when using windows 7 home premium. Basically the problem im having is that although the picture is displayed on the external monitor it is only displayed in a small rectangle in the middle of the screen, with thick black areas filling up the rest of the space.

Annoyingly, when using Ubuntu 10.04 it works perfectly, displaying at the correct resolution and occupying the whole screen so I know my hardware is physically capable (Both PC and monitor).

Hardware wise, I'm using an Acer 5740g laptop with Intel GMA HD graphics.
The TV/Monitor is an LG 26LC46.

Answer (score 0):

You should try playing around with the screen settings. (Right click desktop, personalize and then the last choice on the window that comes up)

There should be many ways to change the screen size. For example, there should be a window that shows both monitors labeled as 1 and 2. Just hover over with your mouse on the number that corresponds to the TV/Monitor and then drag your mouse away or toward you so that you can increase the little image of the monitor on the screen. Depending on how big or small you make it, the change will be reflected on your TV/Monitor once you press apply.